# jquery mobile: how to completely remove the pre-loader from jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, preloader

By changing the CSS for jquery mobile you can remove the pre-loader image on page reloads, but still a grey circle appears on page reloads.

What would be the way to remove the preload indication in jquery mobile all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to disable it altogether.

Try using this on `mobileinit` event:

```
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
```

This should fully disable it:

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()
```

More about this (with some examples) can be found in jQuery mobile documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html).

Comment: Any thoughts on why this won't work in 1.4? (see below)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer was not working for me in jQuery Mobile 1.4.  I wanted to completely disable the Ajax loading so I have the

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

already running between the declaring of jQuery and jQuery Mobile files, but I was still seeing the grey circle.

I came up with this in my css file

```
.ui-loader {
  display:none !important;
}
```

and then the grey circle is gone.  But, a tester pointed out that I was still getting a javascript error on the page that it was failing to load ajax-loader.gif.  I searched around and found this in jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css

```
/* Loader */
.ui-icon-loading {
    background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);
    background-size: 2.875em 2.875em;
}
```

So, I just also added this to my css file

```
.ui-icon-loading {
    background:none !important;
}
```

and now the javascript error is gone too.

Comment: Why would you want to disable Ajax entirely?

Comment: I'm in an environment where we use other technologies that do not work with jQuery Mobile Ajax loading.  We want to have the UI enhancements but the Ajax loading of pages into the DOM instead of actually doing a full post back and page load was causing many issues.

Comment: That's fine, but is it relevant to the OPs question?

Comment: yup that worked for me too thank you, could u tell me what that( !important) is supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe SO users could find this useful, I ran to this same problem and found that you can `show | hide` the *loader* using the `$.mobile.loading()` function so:

To show:

```
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'Verificando Datos',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""
});
```

To hide:

```
$.mobile.loading('hide');
```