# bootstrap when is ui-loader created?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a UI with *Bootstrap v3.3.6* and [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/) which is built from Bootstrap but for some reason there is a `ui-loader` component created even though I don't code it myself, I want to know in what scenarios is this element created and how can I prevent it from being created ?

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default">
   <span class="ui-icon-loading"></span>
   <h1>loading</h1>
</div>
```

For the moment all I do is override some CSS and have the `.ui-loader{display:none!important;}` but I know this isn't the best solution, I just haven't found anything on this topic and I can't seem to find the reason.

BTW: I'm no expert with *Bootstrap*

**EDIT**: Turns out that the library that causes this behavior is **jQuery Mobile** but if I remove it, then some components stop working so how is this handled in jquery mobile ?

Comment: This could be created and used by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @TasosK. could you be more specific ?

Comment: In the template you are working, jQuery Mobile is included. My guess is that if you remove the reference to library it will go away.

Comment: mm yes but if I remove the reference, other components stop working :/

Comment: You could try it just to see if I am right or not. If so, you could rephrase and retag your question so that the correct people see your question.

Comment: Maybe you find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/13536620/2851870

Comment: @TasosK., Thank you and although this works, I want to understand why the loader is being rendered in the first place since I'm not making any ajax calls or anything and this loader stays there the entire time.

Comment: Not sure, I believe is part of the jQuery mobile framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can `show | hide` the *loader* using the `$.mobile.loading()` function so:

To show:

```
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'Verificando Datos',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""
});
```

To hide:

```
$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

As to why the loader is being rendered, what I did was to use jQuery CDN but I only used the **script** and not the CSS reference, so what then happened was that the *"loading"* was being displayed at the bottom of the page, as soon as I added the CSS reference this loader went away. **In one page only** (this was *happening in two of my pages)*. The reason I didn't want to include the CSS reference  was because the **design** was being overriden and I didn't want this.

The other page's problem, I solved it by ONLY adding some CSS: `.ui-loader{display: none}`

Hopefully someone can add to this answer, but for the moment I believe it solves my issues.